# new row in datagrid with custom data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two datagrids. The first one is an overview about a time tracking. The second one shows some details.

For example:
The first datagrid contains each day, where a employee works. The second datagrid contains the time stamping for a day.

However, when I add a new stamping row, the controls in the datagrid are empty. That is not really a problem but the datepicker shows the date 01/01/0001.

what i want is when i add a new row, the date field should be filled with the date from the first datagrid.

VIEW:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      x:Name="DgStundenView"
                      Margin="0 0 10 0"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding TimeOverviewList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wochentag" Binding="{Binding Wochentag}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Datum" Binding="{Binding Tag}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Arbeitszeit Soll" Binding="{Binding ArbeitszeitInStunden}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Arbeitszeit gesamt" Binding="{Binding GesamtDauerInStunden}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pausenzeit" Binding="{Binding Pausenzeit}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pausendifferenz" Binding="{Binding PausenDifferenzInStunden}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Arbeitszeit inkl. Pause" Binding="{Binding TatsaechlicheDauerInStunden}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding StempelungVorhanden,Mode=OneWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Info" Binding="{Binding Info}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Wochentag}" Value="Sa">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Wochentag}" Value="So">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>

        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                      x:Name="DgStempelungen"
                      Margin="0 10 10 0"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TimeDetailList}">


            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Reasons" Type="system:String">
                    <system:String>NICHT ANWENDBAR</system:String>
                    <system:String>KRANK</system:String>
                    <system:String>GANZER TAG URLAUB</system:String>
                </x:Array>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding  Id}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="KOMMEN DATUM">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding  ComeBooking}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="KOMMEN UHRZEIT">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <materialDesign:TimePicker Text="{Binding ComeBookingTime, StringFormat=t}"
                                                       Is24Hours="True">
                            </materialDesign:TimePicker>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="GEHEN DATUM">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding GoBooking}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="GEHEN UHRZEIT">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <materialDesign:TimePicker Text="{Binding GoBookingTime, StringFormat=t}"
                                                       Is24Hours="True">
                            </materialDesign:TimePicker>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="GRUND"
                                        ItemsSource="{StaticResource Reasons}"
                                        TextBinding="{Binding Info}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

VIEW MODEL

```
[CanBeNull] private ClassTimeTrackingDayStamp _selectedItem;

[CanBeNull]
public ClassTimeTrackingDayStamp SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (_selectedItem != null)
            TimeDetailList = new ObservableCollection<ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp>(_selectedItem.Stempelungen);
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<ClassTimeTrackingDayStamp> _timeOverviewList;

public ObservableCollection<ClassTimeTrackingDayStamp> TimeOverviewList
{
    get { return _timeOverviewList; }
    set
    {
        _timeOverviewList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

[CanBeNull] private ObservableCollection<ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp> _timeDetailList;

[CanBeNull]
public ObservableCollection<ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp> TimeDetailList
{
    get { return _timeDetailList; }
    set
    {
        _timeDetailList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
public class ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp : ViewModelBase
{
    public DateTime ComeBooking { get; set; }

    public DateTime GoBooking { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan ComeBookingTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan GoBookingTime { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Update**

EVENT OVER MVVM VIEW

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                      x:Name="DgStempelungen"
                      Margin="0 10 10 0"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TimeDetailList}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="AddingNewItem">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=AddNewItemCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
             ...
```

VIEW MODEL

```
public ICommand AddNewItemCommand { get; set; }

#endregion Properties

#region Events

public event EventHandler AddNewItemEventHandler;

#endregion

#region Constructor

public WTimeClockOverviewVM()
{
    AddNewItemCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
    {
        this.AddNewItemEventHandler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    });
}
```

CODE BEHIND

```
public WTimeClockOverview()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = (WTimeClockOverviewVM)DataContext;

    if(vm == null) return;
    vm.AddNewItemEventHandler += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var selectedItemInFirstDg = vm.SelectedItem;

        if (selectedItemInFirstDg != null)
        {
            var newItem = new ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp();
            newItem.ComeBooking = selectedItemInFirstDg.Tag;
        }
    };
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Best regards
Levin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second DataGrid, you can subscribe to `AddingNewItem` event

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="DgStempelungen" 
          AddingNewItem="DgStempelungen_OnAddingNewItem"
          ...
```

In code behind

```cs
private void DgStempelungen_OnAddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    // I'll assume that the Model's Name in first DataGrid collection is StudentItem!
    var selectedItemInFirstDg = DgStundenView.SelectedItem as StudentItem;
    // or you can get the selected item from the DataContext:
    // (DgStundenView.DataContext as MyViewModel)?.SelectedItem;
    if (selectedItemInFirstDg != null){
       // create the new row with data from selectedItemInFirstDg, ex. date, etc...
       e.NewItem = new ClassTimeTrackingDayStamp
       {
            ComeBooking = selectedItemInFirstDg.Date; // for example
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Muhammad, 
thank you for you answer.

I trigger the event via MVVM. The newItem variable is also filled with the correct date from the first datagrid. The problem now is that the property is not displayed in the control. It still says 01/01/001

I have edited my question again.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The approach in my solution do not break MVVM! in your new code, you can do all the logic inside `AddNewItemCommand` and remove all the eventing code.

Now, you say that `newItem` is populated with new values correctly (i.e. `selectedItemInFirstDg != null` is true) except for the `ComeBooking`, which is of type `DateTime`, right? If `Tag` is of type `DateTime` and is not null, then it should work correctly! What is the type of `Tag` and what value does it hold?

Comment: Tag is not null and is of type `public DateTime Tag { get; }`. `newItem.ComeBooking` is not null and has the dateTime value from tag.
Is it possible that the propertie `ComeBooking` will be overwritten again?

Comment: Based on your code, No. You could set breakpoint on ComeBooking setter when you are about to add new row, it should be hit once, if it got hit another time, you could see where that comes from by looking at CallStack window

Comment: Hmm it is still not working... do you also give support via teamviewer?

Comment: It'd be better to share a sample code (ex. via github), so I can check it in my free time, then we could update the Q/A to mention the underlined issue